# BufferedWriter not producing output to File

Tags: java, file, output, bufferedwriter

In my code I have to take every other word starting with the second word and reverse it. The other classes/threads are doing their job fine. I can print the output to the console window and it prints correctly. However, whenever i try to write to a text file I have on my desktop it does not produce any output.

My code:

```
package ProducerConsumerAssignment;

import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;

import java.util.concurrent.BlockingQueue;

/**
 *
 * @author Tyler Weaver
 */
public class WordWriter implements Runnable {

    private final String END_FLAG = "Terminate the queue";
    private static BlockingQueue<CharSequence> in;
    private final File output;

    /**
     * Constructs a WordWriter object
     *
     * @param file the file to write words to
     * @param queue the blocking queue to retrieve words from
     */
    public WordWriter(final File file, BlockingQueue queue) {
        output = file;
        in = queue;
    }

    /**
     * Executes when being called in a thread
     */
    @Override
    public void run() {
        boolean isInterrupted = false;

        while (!isInterrupted) {
            try (BufferedWriter out = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(output))) {
                CharSequence word = in.take();

                if (word.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(END_FLAG))
                    Thread.currentThread().interrupt();

                out.write(word.toString() + " ");
                System.out.printf("%s%n", word);
            } catch (IOException ex) {
                System.err.printf("Error closing the file!%n%s%n", ex);
            } catch (InterruptedException ex) {
                isInterrupted = true;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: what version of java are you using? Are you using try-with to autoclose the writer? http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html

Comment: I have java 1.8. Yes, i was trying the autoclose the writer.

Comment: you have to call flush after out.write(...)

Comment: @bestsss Thats just a good programming practise. But not that necessary in this case.

Comment: @Aditya, not really, it has nothing to do with any practice - the BufferedWriter has 8KiB buffer and before it's fully filled, it won't send anything to the file - which the real problem according to the asker. This thread will be long lived but it doesn't flush the content to the underlying file until closed. However I did miss the open/close is within the loop which basically overwrites the content.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are closing the `BufferedWriter` on every iteration.

You can move the `BufferedWriter` object out of the `while` loop and call `BufferedWriter.close()` at the end.

```
BufferedWriter writer = new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter(String));
while (true) {
    CharSequence word = in.take();
    if (word.toString().equalsIgnoreCase(END_FLAG)) {
        break;
    }
    try {
        writer.write(word + " ");
    } catch (IOException io) {
        break;
    }
}
writer.close();
```

Comment: I don't think thats a problem. Yeah of course thats bad programming. But that is not the problem. The file is opened at every iteration, it is written in the buffer and it is closed. Then again it is opened, written to and close. How is that a problem?

Comment: @Aditya It is overwritten.

Comment: But the question is that `whenever i try to write to a text file I have on my desktop it does not produce any output.` That means that the file doesn't even write once. But according to your saying, this program writes to the file in first iteration and overwrites in every later iteration. That means the file must contain the last line written in the end. No?

Comment: This answer worked for some reason. All of the output is now being written to the file. Is there any reason why this worked over the Try-With-Resources statement?

Comment: I figured out it was the while statement. I have to have the while statement on the outside of the try-with-resources statement.

Comment: @Aditya Please note [Tyler Weaver said what I said](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26560548/bufferedwriter-not-producing-output-to-file/26563662?noredirect=1#comment41753792_26563662).